# Is it possible to develop a game app using unity and use in native android app? How to achieve that?

Tags: android, kotlin, unity-game-engine

I am looking for a solution to integrate a game developed in unity inside native android app.
I want to develop an app using native android.
Want to develop game using unity
And then combine both and make one android app apk.

Comment: If you haven't built a unity game on android yet, just do it first. Your question is too broad.

Comment: @shingo I want to know, if its feasible. If its not possible then we will go with one either native android or unity whole app

Comment: It is feasible and possible

Comment: @shingo, In this case, unity developer provide SO file of game, developed in unity  to android developer.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.